# Symfony command - The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL

Tags: symfony, security, command, entitymanager, sql-grant

Using `Symfony5` I've created a command that executes a certain task that I trigger with :

`docker-compose exec container bin/console app:do-smthg`

Now when this task is triggered it'll go in the database and modify a field so the action is not uselessly repeated for every instance of this entity.

But I can't `persist` / `flush` the object cause :

```
The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL
```

I've done a bit of digging on that and it might come from the fact the a firewall uses `isGranted()` method while launching this command.

`Dependencies:`

```
    protected static string $commandName = 'app:do-smthg';
    private EntityManagerInterface $em;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $em,
        string $name = 'app:send-sms'
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

`Actual method:`

```
    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $instance = $this->instanceRepository->findOneBy(['somefield' => somevalue]);

        if ($entity->getField() == false) {
            // I do something here 
          
            // then I set a field and persist 
            $instance->setField(true);
            $this->em->persist($instance);
            $this->em->flush();
        }

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

The command works fine without the `persist()` and `flush()` method which first triggered this error message.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could workaround the firewall calling `isGranted()` method when I execute this command ?

Or if there is any other kind of workaround that already exists ?

Edit:

My application is using JWT

Comment: So why are you injecting the Security object into your command?  The firewall stuff works with HTTP requests.  I have never seen it come into play for console commands.

Comment: I've updated the issue. The security component not being rl relevent in this case besides trying to get more insight from that point.

Comment: And you are executing this console command directly?  There are no web requests at all involved anywhere in the process?  Maybe you have a doctrine persist/flush event listener someplace that is checking permissions?

Comment: I had a Listener for this entity on `preUpdate() / postUpdate()` that was triggering this issue, Thanks a lot ! If you want to make it a full answer I'll mark it as the one who solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the firewall and related security stuff only applies to HTTP requests.  Console commands don't have users and permissions as such.  So it was puzzling that a simple entity update was apparently triggering isGranted.

Just as a guess I suggested looking into Doctrine events.  It's possible that they could be checking for permissions.  And as it turns out, I guessed right.  I guess the 'value' of this answer is that there is often more going in than meets the eye.

Comment: Same here, I had $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('something') inside a Doctrine onFlush listener. That was not a good idea. Problem solved by removing it.